# In etcd, how do follower campaign only if the follower have the latest data?

Tags: etcd

For example imagine the case where I only want a follower to be eligible to become a leader only if the follower have the latest data.

Is there a way to do that in etcd?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is etcd's (or rather raft's) guarantee that every new leader will contain all **committed** entries, where **committed** entre is one that was replicated to majority of nodes in the cluster. More reading in [raft paper, 5.4 Safety](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf)